# Magento array to string conversion bug

Tags: php, magento

When i run my Magento 1.9 CE website on new php version(7.0.4) it start giving me error

> Array to string conversion in /var/www/bigliving.local/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php on line 555

Previously is on php 5.4 and working fine.

Comment: magento does not support php7 on the fly. You need to add some patch.

Answer (score 7):

Found solution for this issue, i follow the following steps and it works for me.

1. Go in line number on 555 of this file /var/www/bigliving.local/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php change the code to 
   `$out .= $this->getBlock($callback[0])->{$callback[1]}();`
2. Change the magento root folder and index.php permission  to 755

Answer (score 5):

Try the [PHP 7 compatibility extension](https://github.com/Inchoo/Inchoo_PHP7) for Magento 1

**Edit:** As pointed out in the comments below, the PHP 7 compatibility extension is deprecated, and PHP 7.2 support patches have been released: 
https://inchoo.net/magento/magento-1-official-php-7-2-patches/

Comment: That PHP 7 extension is deprecated. "Magento released official PHP 7.2 patches for Magento 1 (September 2018), which means this extension is not needed anymore!!"

Comment: @TawabG That is great news, I'll update my now outdated answer to include that.